# MVC 2 Beta DefaultControllerFactory with Areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, inversion-of-control, areas

Why default factory **WON'T** return full name of the controllers (with namespaces)?
I'm using Service Locator and autofac.

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

using Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation;

namespace Application.Core.MVC
{

        public override IController CreateController(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, string **controllerName**)
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IController>(controllerName);
        }
}
```

I had two home controllers (one under area Blog)

http://localhost/Home

http://localhost/Blog/Home

controllerName return only "Home" without full qualified name for both in above code.
This creates a problem when I try to regiser controllers' names for dependency injection.
Here is how I register controllers right now according  to this situation. Even this brings up the pages without exception. But When I access  http://localhost/Home, both controllers invoked regardlessly.

```
   foreach (var tp in currentAssemblyControllersTypes)
                    builder.Register(tp).FactoryScoped().Named(tp.Name.Replace("Controller", ""));
```

Anyone can help?Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController() method is responsible for returning a controller for the given request.  The controllerName parameter is just the {controller} part of the route.  It's *CreateController()'s* job - not its caller's - to figure out the proper type given the controller name as specified in the URL.

To make this easier, DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController() delegates into two other methods: GetControllerType() and GetControllerInstance().  If you want to use the original controller resolution logic (e.g. type lookup) but just change how types are instantiated, leave the CreateController() and GetControllerType() methods as-is, and just override GetControllerInstance().  This already takes care of the namespace lookup logic you're duplicating and will make your code far simpler.

Comment: Thanks. I should have just use GetControllerInstance().

Answer (score 0):

[Update according to Levi's answer]

1.Register each controller in full name explicitly:

```
 foreach (var tp in currentAssemblyControllersTypes)
                builder.Register(tp).FactoryScoped().Named(tp.FullName)

//Application.Controllers.HomeController
//Application.Areas.Blog.Controllers.HomeController
```

2 .Specify namespace in MapRoute() for Application.Controllers.HomeController in Global.ascx.cs according to  PDC09 demo

```
    routes.MapRoute(
                    "Default",                                              // Route name
                    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
                    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults

                    ,new string [] { "Application.Controllers"}  //Specify namespace

      );

        }
```

3.Override GetControllerInstance() meothod IoCControllerFactory.cs

```
Protected override IController GetControllerInstance(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, System.Type controllerType)
 {
  return (controllerType == null)? base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext,controllerType):ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IController>(controllerType.FullName);
 }
```